# Отличие href от window.location

Tags: php, javascript, html

Имеется кнопка `button`

```
<button class="btn js-goto-link" role="button" href=""
data-goto="https://site.ru" data-goto-referer="true">Вход</button>
```

и js-код обработчик:

```
activate();

function activate() {
    $(document).on("click", ".js-goto-link", gotoLinkHandler);
}

function gotoLinkHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).data('goto');
    var referer = localStorage.getItem('referal');
    window.location.href = href + (referer ? "?referer=" + referer : "");
}
```

нужно кнопку переделать на ссылку `a`, чтобы в атрибуте `href` было значение атрибута `data-goto`, но и чтобы добавлялись в get-запрос параметры `referer`, которые в js-коде вытягиваются из `localStorage`.
Подскажите, как это правильно сделать?
И вообще, есть ли отличие перехода по `window.location.href` от атрибута ссылки `href` ?
P.S. может это нужно сделать с помощью `php` ?

Answer (score 2):

Разница лишь в том, на кого ты передаешь ответственность на переход на новую страницу.
href - Браузер (стандартный сценарий)
window.location.href - Документ

В твоем коде можно поменять 
var href = $(this).data('goto'); на 
var href = $(this).attr('href');

Comment: благодарю за ответ, но хотел бы уточнить. так jquery-метод `.data()` ведь не сильно отличается от `.attr()`. Для чего тогда делать эти лишние манипуляции? т.е. для чего выбирать из `data-goto` или из `href` с помощью .attr(href). С этим вроде хорошо справлялся и прежний вариант?

Comment: @word да, все верно. Раньше метод data использовал attr, а когда у дом объектов появился dataset, метод data начал работать с ним